# How can I add a menu for each content type in hugo

Tags: blogs, hugo, static-site

I have the following directory structure for my [hugo](https://gohugo.io) site:

```
content/
   - posts/
      - some_post.md
   - talks
      - some_talk.md
   about.md
```

I would like the `main` menu for this site to include entries for `posts` and `talks`. Currently I am able to add a menu item for `about`, by adding `menus = main` to the front matter, however, I would like the `posts` and `talks` links to redirect to indexes of their content, rather than be static pages that I maintain directly. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that this is possible using the `menu` configuration in `config.toml`. The `weight` attribute is used for ordering the menus:

```
[menu]

  [[menu.main]]
    identifier = "home"
    name = "home"
    url = "/"
    weight = 10

  [[menu.main]]
    identifier = "blog"
    name = "blog"
    url = "/post/"
    weight = 20

  [[menu.main]]
    identifier = "talks"
    name = "talks"
    url = "/talks/"
    weight = 30

  [[menu.main]]
    identifier = "about me"
    name = "about me"
    url = "/about/"
    weight = 40
```

Comment: Is there a way to avoid typing out the [[menu.main]] sections for each page? I.e., can I auto generate this list adding one item for each .md file in content/ ?